# Why use java.util.List instead of java.util.Set for relations in Ebean

Tags: java, jpa, orm, ebean

I see that many examples use List for "many" relations, however, Set seems to better fulfil the role since lookup can happen in O(1) while the list search is O(N/2). Is there any reason why List is the preferred type to use?

Comment: People usually like to keep insertion order and allow duplicates, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check yourself, Ebean's authors answered it already with details in article:

[List Set Map or Collection?](https://archive-avaje-org.github.io/manydatatypes.html)

You'll find there a sumarized description of each type and also comparison between chosen types.

Comment: Thanks! They seem to have messed up the Map example but the description is pretty concise.

Comment: link not working. could u add description here if there is?

Comment: @MohdAdnan Google is your friend :) https://archive-avaje-org.github.io/manydatatypes.html

Comment: As the author of the article I'm afraid I left out what I think is the major issue with Set which is that it relies internally on the use of equals() and hashCode().  Set is only as good as the equals()/hashCode() implementation and on mutating beans this is difficult (has compromises).  Implementing equals() and hashCode() on beans that mutate and sometimes do not have an @Id value populated can lead to a lot of confusion.  I never use Set in my ORM model.

Answer (score 3):

Duplication is important only in case of ManyToMany relations, in other cases the ORM handles duplications in List as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation you use.

1. [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) contain no dublicates while you can hold dublicates in List.
2. [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) stores items in the inserted order.

Comment: a LinkedHashSet also stores items in the inserted order.

Comment: I didn't say anything like "implementations of Set cannot store items in the inserted order".

Answer (score 1):

`List` and `Set` are semantically different. Only looking at the lookup times is a bad idea and can lead to serious problems further down the line.

`List` can have duplicates, `Set` cannot.
`List` also guarantees access by index, which `Set`s do not. (Although some `Set` implementations of course might.)

Answer (score 0):

I have always assumed that a List preserves any order that was the result of the query to the underlying database.